# is it possible to make an application supporting both of Eddystone-URL and Eddystone-Uid?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uid, eddystone, eddystone-url

I'm trying to build an application supporting both of Eddystone-URL and Eddystone-Uid. is it possible ? because with Eddystone-uid only my app work perfectly, and with Eddystone-Url only same thing, but when I put them both in the same app, I get problem with the Eddystone-Uid, I get an error while subscribing to the google Nearby Messages Api. 
Thank you :)

Comment: ps: Url keeps working well

Comment: Please show your code that sets up the subscription and the details of the error message you get.

Comment: now when I run the Eddystone-Uid (only) application I get the same error --'' I don't why, the error is : TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS, the exactly same code was working this morning lol --"